# Tween the width of object without moving the object in Actionscript 3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I am trying to do a apply a tween for the width property on a MovieClip Object but every time it changes the width and the position too, and I don't want that. I want to change the width going to one side without changing the x and y of the object.

I tried both of thes and they gave the same result.

```
var c:Tween = new Tween(left, "scaleX", Strong.easeOut, 1, 1.5,20,true);
var c:Tween = new Tween(left, "width", Strong.easeOut, 20, 200,20,true);
```

I think it is applying the transformation according to a center of the movie clip. but I don't know how it can be changed.

any help ?

Comment: Question; are you not getting a conflict error for `c` with the above?

Comment: I didn't use the both in the same time, but the both gave me the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is fact that you don't draw your movie clip correctly and it's bounding box dont start from x,y, 0;

what you can do

1. fix movie clip to have graphics in 0,0 position.

or

2. put your "left" object inside another object at position 0,0 and than scale.

or

3. you can proportionally move the x coordinate also while re size animation is working

```
var c:Tween = new Tween(left, "width", Strong.easeOut, 20, 200,20,true);
var c1:Tween = new Tween(left, "x", Strong.easeOut, left.x, left.x+delta*200/(2*20),20,true);
```

where delta is offeset of your image inside movie clip.

Answer (score 0):

First of, shy away from the default Tween engine. There are way better alternatives for that (that's the main reason, the default Tween engine hasn't received any attention from the platform devs in a long while). Some possibilities may be [found here](http://www.leebrimelow.com/?p=516), or over the web.

Yes, the fact, that object changes position, when tweening the width of it, shows that it's registration point is not on coordinate 0 relative to that object. The solutions are:

1. If you have the possibility, change the object's registration point. Maybe via Flash IDE or programatically lay down components, such as the reg point would be at 0, relative to the object.
2. Shift it right by half the expansion value, every iteration.

This little snippet explains that, translating it into tweens should be easy:

```
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, _loop);
function _loop(event:Event):void
{
    derp.width += 10; // every iteration makes width 10 px bigger
    derp.x += 5; // 10 / 2 = 5; might want to calculate this dynamically.
}
```

Bear in mind, this only works well, if the registration point is on the dead center (on x axis) on the object.